# I need to check MD5 of a large file in client machine before uploading into server in ASP.NET.

Tags: asp.net, md5

I need to check MD5 of a large file in client machine before uploading into server in ASP.NET.

What shall I do to make it happen?

Thanks in advance.

-Sanjay